# What should I do in order that the Lock Screen will turn blank/Computer will sleep? - Cinnamon 3.2.8 (Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Tags: screen, cinnamon, screensaver, lock

Just installed Cinnamon 3.2.8 in Ubuntu 16.04.1.
The Screensaver/Lock Screen wouldn't turn blank after a few minutes, 
and would remain on a Screensaver Mode all night. 
The computer just wouldn't sleep after I lock it. 
What should I do in order that the Lock Screen will turn blank? 
I cannot possibly find an option in the Screensaver's Settings.

Help much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want Cinnamon, you may want to consider Linux Mint instead of Ubuntu, because Mint is based on Ubuntu and comes with Cinnamon by default.

Comment: Look in system settings and then `brightness and lock`, I don't have mate to check this but I guess it is the same.

Comment: It isn't the same.

Comment: The computer just wouldn't sleep after locking it...

Comment: You can write your own script using samples floating around for Ubuntu and customizing it for cinnamon. Sorry I don't use it myself though.